# double encoded filename in ContentDisposition non-ascii characters

Tags: c#, encoding, http-headers, content-disposition, httppostedfile

I am having an issue with the filename in my `Content-Disposition` being mime/quoted-printable encoded but `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` is not decoding the value, instead i get 'filenames' like:

> =?utf-8?B?Zm9vIOKAkyBiYXIubXNn?=

It should say "foo – bar.msg"

The wireshark captured Content-Disposition is:

> form-data;name=\"file\";filename=\"=?utf-8?B?Zm9vIOKAkyBiYXIubXNn?=\"

My client code:

```
string address = "http://localhost/test";
string filename = "foo – bar.msg";
Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    // Create a stream content for the file
    using (MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
        fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
            new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "\"file\"",
            FileName = filename
        };
        fileContent.Headers.ContentType = 
            new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        content.Add(fileContent);

        Uri requestAddress = new Uri(address);

        // Post the MIME multipart form data upload with the file
        HttpResponseMessage response = 
            client.PostAsync(requestAddress, content).Result;
    }
}
```

My server code

```
public void Post()
{
    // this line results in filename being set to the encoded value
    string filename = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].FileName;
}
```

Is there any way to get the `HttpFileCollection` to decode the values? or more likely, is there a way to prevent my client code from double-encoding the value?

Because the content-disposition is in the multi-part boundary section I cannot use `Request.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition` as it is `null`? Is there a way to get an instance of `ContentDispositionHeaderValue` from the body of a multi-part form data request?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when try to get the FileName from files with name with special chars, in my case using accents.

My solution was, in server side:

1. Remove this parts  **=?utf-8?B?** Zm9vIOKAkyBiYXIubXNn **?=**
2. The result Zm9vIOKAkyBiYXIubXNn is a base64 string, use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get a byte[] -> `var myBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("Zm9vIOKAkyBiYXIubXNn");`
3. Decode bytes into a UTF8 string: `string utf8String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myBytes);`, and you will get your original file name
4. Optional: remove diacritical accents from your result string

PD:

> Esto sirve para obtener `httpPostedFile.FileName` de archivos con nombre con caracteres
>   especiales o acentos.

Regards!